# CakePHP 3 prefix (admin) bake templates

Tags: php, cakephp, prefix, cakephp-bake

Can anyone tell me where/how to save the new bake template for prefix routing? When I bake a controller with --prefix Admin it creates the Controller/Admin/controller.php file from the Template/Bake/Controller/controller.php file instead of from the Template/Bake/Controller/Admin/controller.php file. But I want different code generated in the main controller and in the Admin/controller.

Comment: Bake Admin plugin with MVC structure

Comment: But where to save the bake template files for the admin controller and views then?

Comment: plugins/Admin/src/Template/Bake/Template/.  read more  at http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#creating-a-bake-theme

Comment: I'm asking myself if it's a good idea to create a separate Admin plugin because: 1. The admin pages are an inherent part of the main (CMS-) system; and 2. All plugins I need to create will all have front- and back-end (admin) pages. Does this mean for each plugin I need to create 2 plugins, 1 for the frontend and one for the admin? And does the Plugin's Admin plugin then be placed within the Plugin's plugin folder of within the main Admin plugin's plugin folder?

Comment: I do not know what you are planning, but if you need a separated admin bake template, then create "AdminBake" plugin and there save your custom bake template. Then use this bake template to create prefixed controllers, etc. where you want.